# Update Mock response based on the request in SoapUI

Tags: xml, groovy, xsd, soapui

I'm trying to make a solution(*Mock Service Script Dispatch*) for my application with following features:

- user is allowed to upload XSD file and Groovy script for dealing with XML based on the XSD
- XSD file contains two root elements, say "request" and "response"
- Let we have a module generating "request" already
- user Groovy script accepts "request" and generates "response", for example,

  if(request.xxx == 5) {
      response.yyy = 6
  }

What is the best solution for the application?

---

@Rao

Example, user uploads

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:test">
<xs:element name="TestRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="data" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="TestResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="data" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

and script:

```
response.data = request.data + 'xxx'
```

There are some applications which can creates a properly formed "requests" (here TestRequest). So I can parse this requests as XML DOM, for example.
Then the "request" is passed as argument to Groovy script above.

request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestRequest xmlns="urn:test">
    <data>data</data>
</TestRequest>
```

response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestResponse xmlns="urn:test">
    <data>dataxxx</data>
</TestResponse>
```

(actually this is Java application and Groovy script would be run via Java Scripting API)

Comment: just some ideas where to dig: soapui (community edition) building xml based on xsd (wsdl). you can check how they do that. when you have xml - easy to do what you need with groovy..

Comment: Are you trying to use `Script` *Dispatch of Mock Service*?

Comment: @Rao yeap. It will be a service mocking some protocol (say, “XXX”) based on SOAP, so a SOAP envelope contains XXX envelope, which contains “response” envelope.

Comment: Would you mind showing sample input request and expected response to be created?

Comment: @Rao I have updated the issue with example included

Comment: Thank you for the update. Can you show the screen shot of mock service?

Comment: @TimurAkanaev, can you please check the solution and see if that helps?

Comment: @Rao thanks for participating to discuss the issue. At the first sorry for my awfull English. 

I think I did not describe the problem properly and the issue name is not quite correct: there's neither dealing with SoapUI nor with Mock Service Script Dispatch. "soapui" tag is unwanted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **Script** for dispatch of Mock Service:

```
assert mockRequest.requestContent, 'Request is null or empty'
log.info mockRequest.requestContent 
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(mockRequest.requestContent)
context.data = xml.'**'.find {it.name() == 'price'}?.text() + 'xxx'
```

In the response have property expansion as shown below as place holder. As soon as request hits mock service, the values is read from the request, and set the desired value (NOTE: `${data}`) for `<data>` element of the response and sent it in the response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestResponse xmlns="urn:test">
    <data>${data}</data>
</TestResponse>
```